# Recoger variable localStorage AJAX desde archivo PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Mi duda es saber si es posible recoger una variable en localStorage desde PHP sin necesidad de enviarla.

Pretendo recoger datos en una consulta donde activo una opción en un listado y envío un formulario pero quiero determinar si el usuario está logeado y ésta es la variable que tengo en localstorage. No puedo enviarla desde el formulario porque es un listado (o no se hacerlo).

Algo similar a recoger el valor de un $_SESSION['dato'] en PHP.

Espero haberlo planteado correctamente. Pido disculpas si no es así.

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

No, no es posible. El valor de `localStorage` es del lado del cliente y `php` es de lado servidor. No existe manera de transmitir datos así como así. La única solución es enviarlos. Por ejemplo con `ajax`

Answer (score 1):

Acceder a una variable localStorage mediante PHP sin enviarla es imposible, dado que para que se genere esa interacción entre "front" (js) y "servidor" (php) hace falta un envío de por medio... ($.POST)

Lo que podrías hacer es hacer que el listado cargue el contenido mediante una petición AJAX, en ese caso podrías pasar localStorage en un parámetro. No es muy complejo y te resultará tremendamente útil para dicho cometido.

Espero haberme explicado bien, cualquier duda, tell me ^_^

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. La variable ya la tengo generada (SendIt), lo que necesito es crear una consulta mysql en el php destino que tenga un WHERE idarticulo=variablelocalstorage, solo que a esta página le paso otras variables via post. Yo había pensado en algo similar a  $_SESSION que almacena la sesion en el navegador cliente

Comment: Pero vas a tener el problema de generar esa variable $_SESSION, que para hacerlo tienes que o bien recargar la página o bien enviarla por AJAX. Eso tenlo en cuenta ;) de ahí no te escapas.